# The degree of the polynomial $\ W(x) $ is equal $\ 2015$. Knowing that $\ W(n)= \frac{1}{n}$ for $\ n = 1,2,...,2016$ calculate $\ W(2017)$.

Tags: polynomials

The degree of the polynomial $\ W(x) $ is equal $\ 2015$. Knowing that $\ W(n)= \frac{1}{n}$ for $\ n = 1,2,...,2016$ calculate $\ W(2017)$. Please help

Comment: Consider the polynomial $f(x) = xW(x) - 1$. What is $f(n)$ for $n=1,2,3,\ldots$ ? Use this to factor $f(x)$.

Comment: Raffaele, Can you explain why $\ W(2017)=0$?

Comment: A question like this can have just ONE answer $$W(2017)=0$$
Edit.
I left the page 2 hours ago without refreshing it and I did not see the answer below. Anyway: my thought has been the following. The inventor of the question put $2015$ as often happens in context question, but I was convinced that the answer would be the same for a degree like, let's say, $3$. I made the algebra (in a less sophisticated way wrt Julian) and discovered  the answer is zero. Call it HOPEFULLY INDUCTION, but it worked :)

Comment: $$W_3(x)=a x^3+b x^2+c x+d$$
Plug the values
$$\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
 a+b+c+d=1 \\
 8 a+4 b+2 c+d=\frac{1}{2} \\
 27 a+9 b+3 c+d=\frac{1}{3} \\
 64 a+16 b+4 c+d=\frac{1}{4} \\
\end{array}
\right.$$
Get the actual $3$rd degree polynomial
$$W_3(x)=-\frac{x^3}{24}+\frac{5 x^2}{12}-\frac{35 x}{24}+\frac{25}{12}$$
Evaluate $W(5)$ and get $0$ as result

Answer (score 2):

The polynomial of degree $2015$ is uniquely determined by the 2016 predescribed values. Since 
$$W(x)=\frac{1-\prod_{n=1}^{2016}\big(\frac{x}{n}-1\big)}{x}$$
has the correct values for $n=1,\dots,2016$, $W$ has to be of this form. Also note that the given formula is indeed a polynomial since the constant term in the numerator vanishes. Thus we can conclude that $W(2017)=0$.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not understand :(

Comment: @math.trouble $$\frac{1-\prod _{n=1}^4 \left(\frac{x}{n}-1\right)}{x}=-\frac{x^3}{24}+\frac{5 x^2}{12}-\frac{35 x}{24}+\frac{25}{12}$$